# Showing WOD at the specific day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Im creating an application where an user can see what workout of the day a trainer will tell him to do. This workout is going to be in the homepage of the app.

The trainer is going to upload the wods weekly, i want to show just one wod per day.

I thought that if i gave the WOD model an integer attribute called wday, so i can do the logic if Wod.wday == Date.today.cwday i would achieve this. This is not working at all, im getting an error at my static_pages controller.

Heres the code:

Wod model:

```
class Wod < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user

  def this_day
    Date.today.cwday == self.wday
  end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :wods   

 def feed
  Wod.this_day
 end
```

Static pages controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
      if logged_in?
        @wod = current_user.wods.build
        @feed_items = current_user.feed
    end
  end

  def contact
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Im getting the following error:

> NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home undefined method
>   `this_day' for #<Class:0x007f5870c1e7b8> Did you mean? third

I would like to know how to get this done, any help would be appreciated!

BTW: It works perfectly if i do in the user model Wod.all, but i dont want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home undefined method
>   `this_day' for #<Class:0x007f5870c1e7b8>

The problem lies here `Wod.this_day`. If you want to call `this_day` on `WOD` then you need to add it as a `class` method.

Change

```
def this_day
  Date.today.cwday == self.wday
end
```

to

```
def self.this_day
  Date.today.cwday == wday
end
```

Alternate solution is to use `scopes`.

```
class Wod < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  scope :this_day, -> { where(wday: Date.today.cwday) }
end
```

Comment: now it gives me this error: NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home
undefined method `wday'

Comment: @Cesar Do you have `wday` column in `wods` table? Try doing `Wod.column_names` and paste the result here

Comment: irb(main):020:0> Wod.column_names
=> ["id", "warmup", "inbetween", "content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "wday"]

Comment: **NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home
undefined method `wday' for #<Class:0x0055ce705a5a20>

Extracted source (around line #5):              

  def self.this_day
    Date.today.cwday == self.wday
  end

end**

Comment: got it! changed the method def self.this_day, imma update with the answet

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Wouldnt achieve it without u

Comment: @Cesar Try changing it to `Date.today.cwday == wday` and tell me this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the method `this_day` to:

```
def self.this_day
  where("wday = ?", Date.today.cwday)
end
```

Comment: I've addded an alternative solution that you might be interested :)